# JSF - after change class have to re-run

Tags: jsf, jdeveloper

I am using JSF with JDeveloper 11.

After changing any of my Java classes, everytime I have to re run whole project to make changes work.

Is there any way to build only the modified Class and continue work without stoping / starting the project?

I have no much experience in both JSF and JDeveloper and just have to make changes in project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you are just changing the JSF file you can just save and reload the browser.
If you are changing other files you will need to re-run.
A work around is here: http://technology.amis.nl/2009/06/26/fast-swap-in-weblogic-103-and-jdeveloper-11g-redeploy-after-compile-in-running-application/

However if you upgrade to 11.1.2.4 or 12c those versions support hot-swap and you can just save and compile all and reload with no need to re-run even when you change multiple files.